# After installing IIS7.5 on windows 7, all static content files get redirected

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-7

I just installed IIS7.5 on my brand new windows 7 box.

I created a new site using .NEt 2.0 DefaultAppPool, and set up permissions on the database and on the disk for that DefaultAppPool user.

All seemed good, until I deployed and visited my site http://localhost:9000

The page itself worked and returned html, but all static content and scripts were redirected to the logon page.

e.g. 
/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js ==>/logon?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fjquery-1.3.2.min.js

This same code when I publish to a live website works flawlessly and is in fact production code.

I had this working fine in Vista IIS7 too, but obviously I haven't set up something properly.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
CV

UPDATE: all URL requests are being redirected to logon page

so if i enter http://localhost:9000/ into the browser i go to http://localhost:9000/logon

which is specified in my config file.

What on earth is deciding my visits should be redirected there? the homepage doesn't have the AUthorize attribute on it.

Comment: Are the web.configs identical on your production and dev box?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that forms and windows authentication are not both set, it should be one or the other - IIS may even give you a warning about it. I was having some strange static file redirect issues and this is what turned out to be the problem.

Comment: If you're using forms auth, also enable anonymous authentication.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Why is my style sheet redirecting me to login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136208/why-is-my-style-sheet-redirecting-me-to-login)

Set Anonymous Access to use the Application Identity instead of IUSR in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. To solve  this issue, you should enable  Anonymous Authentication, which will run under the App Pool identity instead of IUSR in IIS